# unable to complete updating process after first install

Tags: updates

after installing ubuntu 14.04 software center downloaded 540MB. when restarted to apply changes it is taking too long. i've waited for more than two hours process is going on like in the image. it is not continuous. there is a break after every line for 30sec to minute.
now i could not update my OS. how much time do i need to stay after restarting? please help me in this regard.

[image: screenshot]

my specifications: 4GB ddr3 RAM. 500GB HDD.

It is a kernel panic and it continues[image: kernel panic]
i could use my laptop only in previous versions
guide me to have a stable update so that i can use my lap normally

Comment: It's got kernel panic. You may restart your computer (Ctrl+Alt+del) and before Ubuntu starts keep pressing Shift key. As grub displays, choose the older kernel in the list. After it successfully restarts, open terminal and retry `sudo apt-update` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @TungTran It's probably better to convert your comment to an answer

Comment: OK done. May it help you @raj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my look, it's got kernel panic. You may try following steps:

Restart your computer with the hotkeys combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.

Before Ubuntu loading screen displays (the purple one), press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to show Grub loader.

And then select `Previous Linux versions` as in the following figure.

[image]

After it is up, launch Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, enter the commands

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restart Ubuntu

Comment: it's a kernel panic and it continues even after doing the above process

Comment: when you select recovery mode, does it succeed to boot?

Comment: yes..
after getting kernel panic no keys are working...
i held the power key for few seconds to shut it down
i've used the shift key

Comment: Does it mean you can successfully boot with recovery mode, right?

Comment: If so, get it to boot into recovery mode and enter this command to fix the upgrade issue: `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`

Comment: yes 
i choose advanced options for ubuntu
i choosen some previous version

Comment: please select **Drop to root shell prompt** in the recovery menu. Once you are on the root shell, enter the command `apt-get -f dist-upgrade`.

Comment: i failed pal...
i re-installed Ubuntu 14.04
will not make a software Update now

Comment: OK, if it's your choice.

Comment: yes but thats not a final solution
had an assignment to complete
you have supported me well
hope i will overcome this later...